# I want to upload Microsoft Office Word and PowerPoint files onto my WordPress website.View them in another window not in the same window

Tags: wordpress

I want to upload Microsoft Word ,PowerPoint and also .pdf files into my WordPress website,after uploading them I want to view them in another window not in the same window.

I know there are many plugins to view online but I want to view in another window of browser not on the same. Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/slideshare/
Maybe this works, let me know